# How can I resend DocuSign envelope with existing recipients?

Tags: docusignapi

According to DocuSign documentation, we have to use "Modify or Correct and Resend Recipient Information" method in order to resend an envelope. However, this method is also expecting a collection of recipients.

Is there a way to simply resend the envelope to the current recipients?

I had originally thought about something like this:

```
string requestUrl = string.Format("https://{0}/restapi/v2/accounts/{1}/envelopes/{2}?resend_envelope=true", Properties.Settings.Default.Domain, Properties.Settings.Default.AccountNumber, envelopeId);

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(requestUrl);
request.Method = "PUT";
request.Headers["Authorization"] = string.Format("bearer {0}", Properties.Settings.Default.AccessToken);
```

Related question: [Resend DocuSign Emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21565765/resend-docusign-emails)

Comment: You can have a look into URL below:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/40759689/4527664

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe it's currently possible to resend an Envelope to all recipients, without using the "*Modify or Correct and Resend Recipient Information* request (which requires that you supply the recipient information for each recipient you wish to resend the envelope to).  As you noted in your question, this procedure is described [in this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21565765/resend-docusign-emails).

Seems like the main use cases for 're-sending' an Envelope involve scenarios that would most commonly affect only a single/specific recipient within an Envelope. For example:

- A recipient has misplaced or deleted their original "invitation to sign" email.
- A recipient's email address was specified incorrectly the first time around, so you need to re-send the "invitation to sign" email to the new address.
- Etc.

In scenarios like these, it makes sense for the 're-send Envelope' API call to require that you specifically identify the recipient(s) who should receive the email notification again -- because you only want to re-send to the specific recipient(s) who had trouble with the notification the first time around.