# Resend envelope to recipient through docusign API blocked due to locked recipient

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc, docusignapi

In our app we have a way for users to generate docusign envelopes which then get tracked by status and signed through a chain of recipients.

I've added a feature to resend the document in our interface.  Using XML through the API I think I'm correctly requesting a resend of the envelope to recipients that are in the "delivered" status (meaning they were sent the document but haven't signed yet I think).  I followed the concepts here: [Resend DocuSign Emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21565765/resend-docusign-emails)

However I am unfortunately receiving an error when sending the resend request for the document:

ErrorCode: RECIPIENTS_LOCKED

Message: Recipients are locked and cannot be modified.

I went back to the template and looked for options that might lock down changes to recipients (even though no changes are actually being made) and could only find the option "Sender cannot Add, Edit, Delete Recipients" in the Recipients and Routing section of template.  Unchecking this option did not solve the issue though and I still get the same error when trying to resend documents.

Is there another way I can unlock recipients of an envelope that will allow me to resend documents to them using the API?

**Edit**

Endpoint URL: https://na2.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/[accountId]/envelopes/[envelopeId]/recipients?resend_envelope=true

Request Body:

```
string requestBody = "<recipients xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns=\"http://www.docusign.com/restapi\">" +
            "<signers><signer>" +
                "<recipientId>" + recipientId.ToString() + "</recipientId>" +
                "<name>" + recipientName + "</name>" +
                "<email>" + recipientEmail + "</email>" +
            "</signer></signers></recipients>";
```

Comment: Can you share the URL/endpoint you are trying to hit and also the request body?

Comment: Added endpoint and request body, thanks.

Comment: I would think that you would see such a message if you were in fact modifying the recipient information provided in your API call (name change?). I take it these are remote signers since you are using DocuSign emails.  As one additional troubleshooting exercise can you please do a get against the envelope/<envelopeID>/lock endpoint? Are any locks applied?

Comment: Hmm might be trying to change the name but I'm just taking the ID, name and email from the Get Recipients call and passing that back to the resend POST call so I assumed it would stay the same but I'll do some investigating there to make sure.  Perhaps the values are getting changed when I deserialize the XML as input for the POST call.

Comment: Lock check resulted in: EDIT_LOCK_ENVELOPE_NOT_LOCK - The envelope is not locked.  So that doesn't seem to be the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did some more digging on this one and was able to reproduce this behavior under the following conditions:

If you create an envelope from a template and specify the recipientsLock=true on the createEnvelope request, and you perform a correct w/re-send, you must specify a valid recipientID defined on the template. Please make sure that you are using the recipientID value from the GET and NOT the recipientIDGuid or UserID.

API information on creating template w/recipientsLock: 
https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Post%20Template.htm?Highlight=recipientslock

Comment: Luis, thanks for continuing to look into this for me.  Could the recipient lock have been something set on the template in the DocuSign admin panel?  Maybe that was that option "Sender cannot Add, Edit, Delete Recipients" that is now unchecked but still a factor for previous envelopes created before the change?  I looked into my code for embedded sending when creating the envelope and don't see the recipientsLock attribute being set anywhere.

Comment: If you have the "Sender cannot Add, Edit, Delete Recipients" checkbox set on the template, it is the same as recipientsLock=true. There are a few checkboxes when administrating templates so please make sure you unchecked the correct one.

Comment: Does that mean that I can't resend envelopes created when the template had that checked but it should work for new envelopes created with the template now that it's unchecked?  I've verified I've been using recipientID, name and email directly from the GET when trying to resend.

Comment: To be honest from the testing i did on my side, i was able to still perform the email re-send even if the recipientsLock=true was set. I only received the error in the event i specified an incorrect recipientID for the recipient. Sanity check - please make sure you are specifying a recipient on the envelope that is still 'in process' and has not completed signing.

Comment: Always good to check for sanity from time to time.  I did a test where I manually read the GET recipients data and fed them into the API call as manually defined strings with the recipient data (recipientId, name and email) and it still gave me the same result.  I don't suppose it matters that their status is delivered and not sent?

Comment: Finally had an example of a new live envelope being created off the template with that option unchecked and it allowed me to resend no problem.  Thanks.