# DocuSign API to send instant reminder email to pending recipients

Tags: docusignapi

I want to send instant reminder to the recipients who have not signed the document yet through the DocuSign REST API.

Suppose I have sent an envelope to 3 recipients and one recipient have signed it. After some days I want to send instant reminder email to all other pending recipients or some of pending recipients.

I know there is API available to set reminders & expiration details.
Is there any REST API available so we can send reminder email to pending recipients when user want?

Comment: Can you show some some what you have implemented so far?

Comment: Already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21565765/resend-docusign-emails/21567330

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be possible via CORRECT API call. Please use the ?resend_envelope=true URL parameter as well. Info below.

```
REQUEST TYPE:  PUT

REQUEST URL: https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/<accountID>/envelopes/<envelopeID>?resend_envelope=true

REQUEST BODY: {}
```

[API Documentation](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/update/)

Also see this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21565765/resend-docusign-emails)