# DocuSign API to send instant reminder email to recipient along with message

Tags: docusignapi

I am referring to [DocuSign API to send instant reminder email to pending recipients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39117564/docusign-api-to-send-instant-reminder-email-to-pending-recipients). But in this there is no way to send reminder message to recipient.

Can we have such functionality available in API to send reminder message also to recipient?

We have requirement to send message as part of reminder email. Is there any customization available on account for the same in DocuSign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reminder email and it's contents will be the same as the initial email they receive to sign the document. By default the only visual differentiator that this is a reminder email is the word REMINDER which is pre-pended to the email subject.