# Resend Envelope using Docusign not working- user not receiving the email

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to re-send the envelope to Recipient through docusign API, but user is never receiving the email

URI - https://na2.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts//envelopes//recipients

The post is successful, i get a success message but user never receives a email.

There is no correction required. Its a reminder email, i know in the account there is a setting to send the reminder, but i am using nintex "send docusign document" activity to send the email to the user initially. So the default docusign reminder is not working and i using the api to send reminder.Any help???

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please "check" (accept) the right answer to your questions. And upvote all useful answers, including those for others' questions. Please ask a new question when you have one, don't add a question as a comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use the "**resend_envelope=true**" query string parameter.

```
PUT 
https://{{env}}.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/{{accountId}}/envelopes/{{envelopeId}}/recipients?resend_envelope=true
```

Answer already provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21565765/resend-docusign-emails).

Comment: The envelope is re-sent, but now another issue. I receive a message "<user> has corrected SharedDocuments1.pdf
As a result, you no longer have access." I am trying to achieve the same by using https://na2.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/<acctid>/envelopes/<envelope id>/views/recipient and I am getting the following url  https://na2.docusign.net/Signing/startinsession.aspx?t=<guid> - even this one is expiring after few tries