# How to resend a document in DocuSign API

Tags: docusignapi

I need to be able to resend an already sent API.  Either because an email was lost, or perhaps a signer declined, and I want them to sign again.

I am using the call below.  According to the docs, I need to add the 'resend' to the envelope.  But I can't find where I put that.  Does anyone have any idea how to add that flag?

```
EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi();
EnvelopeSummary envelopeSummary = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(accountId, envDef);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If a signer has **declined**, you'll have to create/send a brand new Envelope, because once a signer declines, the Envelope is in a terminal state (cannot be completed).

If you need to re-send the signing invitation email to specific recipient(s), for example, because the initial email has been misplaced, you'll need to use the **Update Envelope Recipients** operation to do so (more details about this scenario are available in my answer here: [Resend DocuSign Emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21565765/resend-docusign-emails)). To do this with the DocuSign C# SDK, your code would look like this:

```
envelopesApi.UpdateRecipients(accountId, envelopeId, recipients, options);
```

...where `recipients` specifies the recipient(s) that you want to re-send emails to, and `options` is an `EnvelopesApi.UpdateRecipientsOptions` object with the `resendEnvelope` property set to (the string value) **true**.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks so much.  I wasn't sure if I could resend a decline.  So that's great advice.  The 'Update Recipients' call is really the one I was looking for.  I was looking for something like 'Resend' or similar.  That's why I couldn't find it.

Thanks again!

Comment: No problem at all; happy I could help!

Comment: @KimBrandl Is there a way to resend the envelope with this method without defining the recipients (again)?

Comment: @NiAu I don't think it's possible to resend the envelope without specifying the recipients. I tested this just now, and the server returns the error code `INVALID_REQUEST_BODY` and error message `The request body is missing or improperly formatted.` if I don't specify recipients. This makes sense, really -- because this API endpoint was originally designed for updating recipient info (even though you *can* use it to resend an envelope without changing recipient info) -- and also because in most re-send scenarios you'll want to resend to a specific person, not to all recipients.

Comment: @KimBrandl Thx for your quick answer! I also tested it that way, but I hoped that because it was an optional parameter that it would resend the envelope to all 'open' signers. But then I have to add all original recipients. Will the DocuSign system filter out the 'completed' signers or do I need to only pass those 'open' signers'?

Comment: @NiAu with a bit more research, I've found a way to resend an envelope to all pending recipients:  send a `PUT` request to this endpoint `https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/<accountID>/envelopes/<envelopeID>?resend_envelope=true` and set the request body to `{}`. Note that this endpoint is no longer the **Update Recipients** endpoint (it doesn't contain `/recipients` at the end).